# Capitalization of non-English words

Tags: discussion

The following question capitalizes non-English words:

> [What is the difference between NABI and RASUL?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-is-the-difference-between-nabi-and-rasul)

I believe this will hurt readability.

How should titles such as this be handled? Should there be quotation marks (when appropriate) around the words, and should they be treated analogous to English words?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I "find" frequent "quotation" marks just "makes" things awkward to "read".  And CAPITALIZING words in THE middle of A SENTENCE isn't really MUCH better.

I generally just *italicize* the non-*English* words, possibly followed by the *translation* (in parentheses).  Much more legible.

Comment: What about non-English words in titles?

Comment: for titles, quotes make sense for 'What does "term" mean?' questions, but otherwise i would just treat them as regular words.  no capitals or anything.  can't remember if you can italicize in titles, but i probably wouldn't bother.